How to stream data from File asynchronously through Rust Http server?
I want to serve a Http stream from Rust backend to be used as src in HTML Audio tag in Tauri frontend.
I decided to use warp and came up with this code:
use futures::{future::FutureExt, pin_mut}; // futures 0.3.30
use hyper::body::{Body, Frame}; // hyper 1.4.1
use std::{collections::VecDeque, fs::File, pin::Pin};
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use tauri::AppHandle; // tauri 2.0.0-rc.16
use warp::{http::Response, Filter}; // warp 0.3.7

struct FileAt {
    file: File,
    at: usize,
}

impl FileAt {
    pub async fn read_part(&mut self) -> Result<VecDeque<u8>, String> {
        // TODO: read asynchronously some data from *file*, starting from *at*
        // TODO: add number of read bytes to *at*
        Ok(VecDeque::new())
    }
}

impl Body for FileAt {
    type Data = VecDeque<u8>;
    type Error = String;

    fn poll_frame(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<Result<Frame<Self::Data>, Self::Error>>> {
        // TODO: trailers frame? (file metadata -> headers)
        if !self.is_end_stream() {
            let f = self.get_mut().read_part();
            pin_mut!(f);
            if let Poll::Ready(out) = f.poll_unpin(cx) {
                Poll::Ready(
                    out.map(|data| {
                        if data.is_empty() {
                            Some(Frame::data(data))
                        } else {
                            None
                        }
                    })
                    .transpose(),
                )
            } else {
                Poll::Pending
            }
        } else {
            Poll::Ready(None)
        }
    }
}

fn data(path: String) -> Result<FileAt, String> {
    let body = FileAt {
        file: File::open(path).or(Err("File open error.".to_string()))?,
        at: 0,
    };
    Ok(body)
}

pub fn run(app: AppHandle) {
    tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async {
        warp::serve(warp::path::param::<String>().map(|path| {
            Response::new(data(path).unwrap())
        }))
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 12345))
        .await;
    });
}

But I ran into usual Rust type system chaos, the trait bound 'warp::hyper::Body: From<FileAt>' is not satisfied is the closest I managed to get to the solution, with the above code. How can I fix the code? I ran out of ideas. Thanks!
I don't want to simply serve it through warp::filters::fs, because getting data from file is only a temporary measure, later the data will be asynchronously retrieved from another source, I plan to replace FileAt with another implementation of hyper::Body.
And perhaps you see some other errors, that I can run into later with this, It's also welcome, but for now I just need help with above the most.
This is output of cargo check:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `warp::hyper::Body: From<FileAt>` is not satisfied
  --> src/server.rs:64:15
   |
64 |           warp::serve(warp::path::param::<String>().map(|path| {
   |  _________-----------_^
   | |         |
   | |         required by a bound introduced by this call
65 | |             Response::new(data(path).unwrap())
66 | |         }))
   | |__________^ the trait `From<FileAt>` is not implemented for `warp::hyper::Body`, which is required by `(_,): Reply`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<&'static [u8]>`
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<&'static str>`
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<Box<(dyn Stream<Item = Result<hyper::body::Bytes, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + Sync + 'static)>>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>`
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<Cow<'static, [u8]>>`
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<Cow<'static, str>>`
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<Vec<u8>>`
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<hyper::body::Bytes>`
             `warp::hyper::Body` implements `From<std::string::String>`
   = note: required for `warp::http::Response<FileAt>` to implement `Reply`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `(warp::http::Response<FileAt>,)` to implement `Reply`
note: required by a bound in `serve`
  --> /snip/snip/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/warp-0.3.7/src/server.rs:26:17
   |
23 | pub fn serve<F>(filter: F) -> Server<F>
   |        ----- required by a bound in this function
...
26 |     F::Extract: Reply,
   |                 ^^^^^ required by this bound in `serve`

error[E0599]: the method `run` exists for struct `Server<Map<impl Filter + FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection> + Copy, {closure@server.rs:64:49}>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/server.rs:67:4
   |
64 | /         warp::serve(warp::path::param::<String>().map(|path| {
65 | |             Response::new(data(path).unwrap())
66 | |         }))
67 | |         .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 12345))
   | |         -^^^ method cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   | |_________|
   |
   |
  ::: /snip/snip/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/hyper-0.14.30/src/body/body.rs:38:1
   |
38 |   pub struct Body {
   |   --------------- doesn't satisfy `warp::hyper::Body: From<FileAt>`
   |
   = note: the full type name has been written to '/snip/snip_lib-3ea8e680ad041633.long-type-16360758156595682726.txt'
   = note: consider using `--verbose` to print the full type name to the console
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `warp::hyper::Body: From<FileAt>`
           which is required by `(warp::http::Response<FileAt>,): Reply`

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/server.rs:26:9
   |
26 |         mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
   |         ----^^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.


If anybody could suggest a different approach to the problem, it'd be also highly appreciated.
